# IE11 Javascript faster with profiler enabled

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-11

My website (www.transferxl.com) relies on Javascript for compressing data. Compressing a 25MB large chunk takes about 1-2 seconds with most browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, ...). IE11 takes over 40 seconds for exactly the same operation.

I thought IE11 was just painfully slow, so I decided to enable the profiler and see what is happening. To my surprise the same chunk was compressed in 2-4 seconds. Although still slower than Chrome, it was way faster then before.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to www.transferxl.com.
2. Open the developer console (F12).
3. Add a (compressible) file that is larger than 25MB.
4. Transfer the file and watch the console

You'll see a message how long it takes to compress the chunk of data.

5. Refresh the window (while still on www.transferxl.com).
6. Start the profiler.
7. Add a the same file again.
8. Transfer the file and watch the console

You'll see that the same block is now compressed much faster. You can also try it in reverse order. Results are stable. With the profiler on IE seems to compress 10-20 times faster then without the profiler.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? The profiler output doesn't show anything alarming. Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: That is so weird. Maybe an IE power saving feature that turns itself off when the profiler is used?

Comment: Have you tried the opposite test? First try it with the profiler enabled, then disabled. If you assumption holds true then the first run should be faster than the second. You want to weed out any optimizations made to the browser when running what are essentially the same tasks more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing exactly what you asked, and the uploads took less than 2 seconds on both Google Chrome (39.0.2171.65 m) and Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.17420). It appears as if Microsoft may have released this fix in one of their more recent updates. As far as I have seen, nothing of this sort was mentioned in the [changelogs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3003057). Yes, I ran IE with the profiler disabled. I presume that the issue may have been caused by IE assigning process priority to scripts running with the profiler attached, since the profile also needs to function and render its output (supposedly) without affecting the functioning of the page itself. The compensation does not noticeably affect the computer's processor consumption in any way, but somehow just utilizes existing memory that has been allocated by IE prior to opening the profiler.